# How can i convert .odt file to html using python

Tags: python, ms-word, odt, mammoth

In windows, document file ends with .docx

To convert the content of .docx file to HTML string, i used [mammoth package](https://github.com/mwilliamson/python-mammoth) and everything works perfectly.

Now i face with .odt file in Unix system, which is using LibreOffice.

The problem is: Is there any package like Mammoth to convert .odt file to HTML?

If there is no choice, maybe i have to convert from .odt file to .docx file, just to reuse mammoth. Is there any package of python to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried looking at the https://pypi.org/project/odfpy/ package? It seems to be a pretty handy wrapper for manipulating ODT files.

More specifically inside that package there seems to be a function / API that allows you to convert an ODT file into some form of HTML so try looking at that.

*odf2xhtml - Convert ODF to (X)HTML* on the package link should point you in the right direction. I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: Let me try this. If i get some good news, i'll be back to accept the answer. Thank you